# Combining table information

Tags: sql

I have a simple database with three tables:

**contributes**
[image: contributes Table]

**payment**
[image: payment Table]

**user**
[image: user Table]

Whereby **contributes** is a relationship table between the two **user** and **payment** tables. My problem is that when executing an SQL statement to retrieve relationship properties - such as the 'paid' value - and thus include the contributes table in the statement, the results from the query seem to be returned twice. For example, `SELECT * FROM user, payment, contributes;` produces:

[image: Query Result]

Whereas `SELECT * FROM user, payment;` produces:

[image]

My only guess is that the `SELECT` statement is simply combining EVERY row of **users** with EVERY row of **payments** with EVERY row of **contributes**, much like a power set?

Forgive me if I'm missing anything obvious, any help would be much appreciated. Also, apologies for the weird table name formatting in the images, that's just how phpMyAdmin exported them!

Comment: You're doing Cartesian joins when you don't specify the join criteria. Search stackoverflow for how to join sql tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.host, c.paid, p.name, p.total, p.portion
FROM user u
INNER JOIN contributes c
ON u.id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN payment p
ON c.payment_id = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks! Why would it be so extensive though when 'user_id' and 'payment_id' are foreign keys to the other table IDs?

Comment: @CallanHeard Because foreign keys are for maintaining referential integrity, not for performing implicit joins.